# Advice on populating a dataframe based on an existing one

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm seeking advice on populating a dataframe in pandas. I've now created a dataframe that looks like A:
[image]

However, eventually, it should looks like something in B, hopefully:
[image]

Could anyone suggest how to create a dataframe like B on top of A, if I have relevant data values.

Any comments or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have two dataframes that look like A. One for feature F1 and one for F2.

Then you create B like this:

```py
a1 = ...  # assuming A1, A2 already have correct index A, B, C as depicted.
a2 = ...
a1['Features'] = "F1"
a2['Features'] = "F2"

b = (pd.concat([a1, a2], axis=0)
     .set_index("Features", append=True)
     # Swing the new index level - Features - around to become a column level instead.
     .unstack("Features"))
```

You've named the column level "Features" but I'd suggest using "Feature" instead, if you can.

There is also an alternate way to do the same thing, also seen in this question: [How to make dataframe behave such as pandas_datareader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72502298/how-to-make-dataframe-behave-such-as-pandas-datareader/72502334)

```py
(pd.concat([a1, b2], axis='columns', keys=pd.Index(["F1", "F2"], name="Features"))
 # swap hierarchy order of column levels
 .swaplevel(-2, -1, axis=1)
 # restore sorting to that of a1 columns - assuming a1, a2 have the same cols
 .reindex(columns=a1.columns, level=0)
)
```