# How to make dataframe behave such as pandas_datareader

Tags: pandas

If you see this following code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import pandas as pd

stocks = 'f', 'fb'

df = web.DataReader(stocks,'yahoo')
```

The resultant `df` looks like this:

```
Attributes  Adj Close              Close  ...        Open      Volume            
Symbols             f          fb      f  ...          fb           f          fb
Date                                      ...                                    
2017-06-05   9.280543  153.630005  11.25  ...  153.639999  42558600.0  12520400.0
2017-06-06   9.173302  152.809998  11.12  ...  153.410004  44543700.0  13457100.0
2017-06-07   9.132055  153.119995  11.07  ...  153.270004  37344200.0  12066700.0
2017-06-08   9.156803  154.710007  11.10  ...  154.080002  40757400.0  17799400.0
2017-06-09   9.181552  149.600006  11.13  ...  154.770004  30285900.0  35577700.0
              ...         ...    ...  ...         ...         ...         ...
2022-05-27  13.630000  195.130005  13.63  ...  191.360001  54195700.0  22562700.0
2022-05-31  13.680000  193.639999  13.68  ...  194.889999  79689900.0  26131100.0
2022-06-01  13.550000  188.639999  13.55  ...  196.509995  50726200.0  36623500.0
2022-06-02  13.890000  198.860001  13.89  ...  188.449997  42979700.0  31951600.0
2022-06-03  13.500000  190.779999  13.50  ...  195.979996  43574400.0  19447300.0

[1260 rows x 12 columns]
```

If you want to see the closing value for 'f'

```
df['Close'].f
Out[17]: 
Date
2017-06-05    11.25
2017-06-06    11.12
2017-06-07    11.07
2017-06-08    11.10
2017-06-09    11.13
 
2022-05-27    13.63
2022-05-31    13.68
2022-06-01    13.55
2022-06-02    13.89
2022-06-03    13.50
Name: f, Length: 1260, dtype: float64
```

What is this method called? For example if you have a few dataframes of random number with different names but same column values; how can one combine them to make it behave such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a dataframe with several levels (a MultiIndex) for its columns. These levels can each have a name and seem to have names in this case ("Attributes" and "Symbols"), but nameless levels also exist.

To look closer at that, I'd use `print(df.columns)`.

Since there are two levels of columns, the following will also work: `df[('Close', 'f')]` i.e. using tuples as the "full column names". These tuples are also what you see if you would take a closer look at `df.columns`.

We can use `pd.concat` to combine two dataframes and do so with a new column level. By default this becomes the topmost level, which we'll have to "work against".

```py
# Given dataframes a, b
# Concatenate in the column direction. Use keys to give the new
# column level names and and give the level itself the name Symbols.


(pd.concat([a, b], axis='columns', keys=pd.Index(["f", "fb"], name="Symbols"))
 # swap hierarchy order of column levels
 .swaplevel(-2, -1, axis=1)
 # restore sorting to that of a's columns - assuming a, b have the same cols
 .reindex(columns=a.columns, level=0)
)
```

---

You can also take a look at `df.stack("Symbols")` which moves the symbols level down into an index level (and you can reset that index level if desired, leaving it as a column). One can use stack/unstack to move back and forth like this, so going the path through unstack is another way to reach the same goal.

If Symbol was a column, you'd do this: `df.set_index("Symbol", append=True).unstack("Symbol")` to turn it into another column level.